# Models/Controllers in subfolders for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm trying to keep the application as neat and tidy as possible because it could get quite large. Already a few days into it I've noticed the following pattern in the models:

```
models/
    prefix_file.rb
    prefix_file2.rb
    prefix_file3.rb
    file.rb
    prefix2_file.rb
    prefix2_file2.rb
```

Is there anyway to organise the models directory into subfolders?

Answer (score 2):

You can namespace your files in directories and use modules.

For example

```
models/
  prefix/
    file.rb
    file2.rb
    file3.rb
  prefix2/
    file.rb
    file2.rb
  file.rb
```

Then inside your files within the directories you would have something like

**models/prefix/file.rb**

```
module Prefix
  class File < ActiveRecord::Base

  end
end
```

To use them you would need to have code like this `Prefix::File.some_method`